# Spring JPA @ManyToOne and @OneToMany delete

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I use Spring Boot backend for my application. I have 2 entities, Post and Comment. There are multiply comments for my posts. What I want:

1. If I delete my post, I want to delete my comments as well.
2. If I delete a comment, I want to delete only that one comment.

Here is my Post entity:

```
@Entity
public class Post{
...
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post")
private Set<Comment> comments;
...
}
```

Here is my Comment entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comment{
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id", nullable = false)
private Post post;
...
}
```

This is how I tried to delete my comment:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{commentId}")
    @RoleSecured({})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> delete(@PathVariable Long commentId) {
        commentRepository.deleteById(commentId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

And this is how I tried to delete my post:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{postId}")
@RoleSecured({})
public ResponseEntity<Object> delete(@PathVariable Long postId) {
    Post post = postRepository.findById(postId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Post not present in database"));
    postRepository.delete(post);
}
```

This is my last try but I tried a lot of things, can you help me please how can I implement both deletes.
Delete of the post exception:

```
021-11-24 15:05:48.479 ERROR 23332 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`buildtogether`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`))
2021-11-24 15:05:48.480  INFO 23332 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-11-24 15:05:48.588 ERROR 23332 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`buildtogether`.`comment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_post_id` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`))
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
```

Delete of the comment exception: no exception, but not delete the comment.

Comment: Everything looks fine. What's the problem? Do you get exceptions?

Comment: Yep sorry, I left the exceptions out, soon I will edit my post.

Comment: When does this occur when deleting post or when deleting comment?

Comment: The error occurs when deleting the post. When I'm deleting the comment, it just simply not delete it without any exception.

Comment: You can not delete row of parent table which is associated with foreign key of child table. first delete child table row then you have permission to delete parent table row

Comment: I tried to add: "post.getComments().forEach(commentRepository::delete)" but it still threw the same error.